# Easiest way to transform an Object into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
 descriptions: {
    1: {
      description: "abc"
    },
    2: {
      description: "def"
    },
    3: {
      description: "ghi"
    }
  }
```

Is there an easy way to transform that object into an array like this?:

```
 descriptions: ["abc","def","ghi"]
```

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way to translate an object into an array like that. Have you tried anything yourself? Also, if you have a series of sequential indices in your object, consider using an array for that as well. Expected output with `:` syntax is unclear--is this a key in an object or a loose variable? You may [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62435437/edit) to add your attempt and clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: `Object.values`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  descriptions: {
      1: {
        description: "abc"
      },
      2: {
        description: "def"
      },
      3: {
        description: "ghi"
      }
    }
};

console.log(Object.values(obj.descriptions).map(({description}) => description))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could flatMap the values of the object.

```js
var descriptions = { 1: { description: "abc" }, 2: { description: "def" }, 3: { description: "ghi" } },
    values = Object.values(descriptions).flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(values);
```

Comment: The object in the question looks like minimal sample data. It should be made clear that this aggregates all keys of all the objects. Happens to work with the sample code, but that's probably not real-world data.

Comment: @slappy, well, it's up to op to show all relevant data. actually i take the data as is.

Comment: come on. op has enough rep (read experience) to ask. if parts are missing, then op will test the proposal and comment accordingly.

Comment: OP can't even find a solution to a simple problem for himself, despite his rep. But as a high rep user, I'd think you'd be aware that irrespective of the rep of the OP, there will be others reading this solution too. Don't get me wrong. It's plenty good for any situation where you know you always want all values from all keys of all objects to be accumulated into a single array, but how likely do you really think that is?

Answer (score 0):

```
descriptions= {
  1: {
    description: "abc"
  },
  2: {
    description: "def"
  },
  3: {
    description: "ghi"
  }
}

var keys = Object.keys(descriptions);
var values = keys.map((key) => descriptions[key].description);
```

`values` will be the array you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

or something like this

```
function f(obj) {
    let array = []
    for (const prop in obj) {
     array.push(Object.values(obj[prop])[0])

    }
    return array
    }
```